# Unable to write to an XML File

Tags: java, xml

I have been working on writing to an XML file with Java. The code is executed without any errors, but the extra piece that I have attempted to add is not successfully added.

What am I missing? How can I correct my method to rewrite the existing file, and add the extra component that I need?

```
public static synchronized AffLink writeAffLinkEntry(String mPrimSysComp, String mSecSysComp, String mPrimSysCompId,
                                                                                                                String mSecSysCompId) throws Exception {

        String primSysCompApiKey = RandomStringUtils.random(50);
        String secSysCompApiKey = RandomStringUtils.random(50);

        //ADD RECORD TO THE XML FILE
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:/App/J/AffLinkList.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("affiliates");
        Element affiliatePairElement = doc.createElement("affiliate_pair");

        affiliatePairElement.setAttribute("prim_sys_comp", mPrimSysComp);
        affiliatePairElement.setAttribute("sec_sys_comp", mSecSysComp);
        affiliatePairElement.setAttribute("prim_sys_comp_id", mPrimSysCompId);
        affiliatePairElement.setAttribute("sec_sys_comp_id", mSecSysCompId);
        affiliatePairElement.setAttribute("prim_sys_comp_api_key", primSysCompApiKey);
        affiliatePairElement.setAttribute("sec_sys_comp_api_key", secSysCompApiKey);

        rootElement.appendChild(affiliatePairElement);
        //      doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        try {
            Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            /*          tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "affiliates.dtd");*/
            tr.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            // send DOM to file
            tr.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
                                        new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("C:/App/J/AffLinkList.xml")));

        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            System.out.println(te.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        //update cache
        affLinkList = syncAffLinkList(true);

        return new AffLink(mPrimSysComp, mSecSysComp, mPrimSysCompId, mSecSysCompId, primSysCompApiKey, secSysCompApiKey);

    }
```

This is what the XML document looks like to begin with, but it could have elements inside of it at a later date.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<affiliates>
</affiliates>
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you need to add the root element to the xml document.

```
doc.appendChild(rootElement);
```

UPDATE:
It seems like you have tried this. So, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve I guess.

Adding the root element works for me, and gives the following result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<affiliates>
    <affiliate_pair prim_sys_comp="prim_sys_comp" prim_sys_comp_api_key="prim_sys_comp_api_key" prim_sys_comp_id="prim_sys_comp_id" sec_sys_comp="sec_sys_comp" sec_sys_comp_api_key="sec_sys_comp_api_key" sec_sys_comp_id="sec_sys_comp_id"/>
</affiliates>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I modified to make the code work properly

```
String primSysCompApiKey = RandomStringUtils.random(50, true, true);
        String secSysCompApiKey = RandomStringUtils.random(50, true, true);

        //ADD RECORD TO THE XML FILE
        File fXmlFile = new File("C:/App/Jl/AffLinkList.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        /*  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();*/

        Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
        Element affiliatePairElement = doc.createElement("affiliate_pair");
        rootElement.appendChild(affiliatePairElement);

        Element sysCompElement = doc.createElement("sysComp");
        sysCompElement.appendChild((doc.createTextNode(mPrimSysComp)));
        affiliatePairElement.appendChild(sysCompElement);

        Element sysCompIdElement = doc.createElement("sysCompId");
        sysCompIdElement.appendChild((doc.createTextNode(mPrimSysCompId)));
        affiliatePairElement.appendChild(sysCompIdElement);

        Element affCompElement = doc.createElement("affSysComp");
        affCompElement.appendChild((doc.createTextNode(mSecSysComp)));
        affiliatePairElement.appendChild(affCompElement);

        Element affCompIdElement = doc.createElement("affSysCompId");
        affCompIdElement.appendChild((doc.createTextNode(mSecSysCompId)));
        affiliatePairElement.appendChild(affCompIdElement);

        Element apiKeyInElement = doc.createElement("apiKeyIn");
        apiKeyInElement.appendChild((doc.createTextNode(primSysCompApiKey)));
        affiliatePairElement.appendChild(apiKeyInElement);

        Element apiKeyOutElement = doc.createElement("apiKeyOut");
        apiKeyOutElement.appendChild((doc.createTextNode(secSysCompApiKey)));
        affiliatePairElement.appendChild(apiKeyOutElement);

        try {
            Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            /*          tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "affiliates.dtd");*/
            tr.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            // send DOM to file
            tr.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
                                        new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("C:/App/J/AffLinkList.xml")));

        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            System.out.println(te.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        //update cache
        affLinkList = syncAffLinkList(true);

        return new AffLink(mPrimSysComp, mSecSysComp, mPrimSysCompId, mSecSysCompId, primSysCompApiKey, secSysCompApiKey);
```